# Bug when editing posts

Tags: bug, editing-help, ios-app

When I am trying to edit this post: *[angular installation failure in Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53466557/angular-installation-failure-in-ubuntu-16-04)* on the Stack Exchange app I am getting a bug.

On my mobile the post is showing like this:

[image: One paragraph of text followed by unformatted code.]

But when I click edit it changes to this:

[image: One paragraph of text followed by a broken image tag.]

And without editing anything when I click preview I get this:

[image: Request failed: This suggested edit changes too much.]

It could possibly be because I’ve edited that post wider, but I am not sure.

Comment: cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315649/this-suggested-edit-changes-too-much this seems to be [status-by-design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268385/158100)